# How can I contact Obama now that he's not in the White House?

Tags: privacy

I was hoping to write an email to President Obama. However, now that the transition to Trump's presidency has officially come to pass, all the search results suggesting to email the White House no longer apply. Does anyone know a way I can electronically contact Barack Obama at present?

I don't know if people will consider this off topic or not, but it's something that should be simple and is yet more complicated than it seems, so I could definitely use a "life-hack" to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to give a more general, more lifehack-esque answer, so I'll instead try to answer "how to save time when trying to contact former government officials". If that were your question, then I'd say a good place to start seems, these days, to be Twitter.

To answer your actual question more directly: https://twitter.com/BarackObama